# Geotools unable to transform EPSG:5359 to EPSG:4326 , returns NAN for coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, point, latitude-longitude, java, geotools

I am using geotools to transform a set of point in chile  EPSG:5359  to  world EPSG:4326

I am using below code

```
transform("6884327.77", "447076.76");

static Coordinate transform(String Easting, String Northing) throws Exception {   
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
    CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:5359");
    //System.out.println(sourceCRS);
    CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory);
    Point point = (Point) reader.read("POINT (" + Easting + " " + Northing + ")");

    System.out.println(point.toString());

    MathTransform mTrans = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS);
    Geometry transformed = JTS.transform(point, mTrans);
    Coordinate cordinatesingle = transformed.getCoordinate();
    Coordinate[] cordinate = transformed.getCoordinates();
    System.out.println(cordinatesingle.getX());
    System.out.println(cordinatesingle.getY());
    return cordinatesingle;
}
```

I debugged and found out it goes into `DefaultCoordinateSequenceTransformer` class and then here it returns `NAN`. Why does it return `NAN`? Do I need another transformer for this?

Comment: Are you sure that the axis order is correct when you build the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source point cannot be in EPSG:5359

https://epsg.org/crs_5359/SIRGAS-Chile-2002.html?

That coordinate system is   `Ellipsoidal 3D CS. Axes: latitude, longitude, ellipsoidal height. Orientations: north, east, up. UoM: degree, degree, metre.`

The units in your coordinates "6884327.77", "447076.76" are probably meters. Find out the proper EPSG code for your data.

Comment: https://epsg.io/?q=chile may help